# Dijkstra not finding correct path

Tags: c#, algorithm, dijkstra

I have implemented Dijkstra's algorithm to find the maximum weight path in an undirected weighted graph. Unfortunately, it doesn't return the best path in all situations. Any help is appreciated figuring out what I did wrong. I've been staring at this code for too long.

```
        graph.AddConnection("A", "B", .5);
        graph.AddConnection("A", "J", .2);
        graph.AddConnection("A", "F", .63);
        graph.AddConnection("A", "Z", .92);
        graph.AddConnection("B", "C", .7);
        graph.AddConnection("B", "E", .112);
        graph.AddConnection("C", "D", .1);
        graph.AddConnection("F", "G", .21);
        graph.AddConnection("G", "D", .92);
        graph.AddConnection("J", "G", .56);
        graph.AddConnection("Z", "D", 0.99);
```

I am trying to find the strongest path from A to G which should be:
AZDG. Instead it is outputting AFG.

```
private void ProcessGraph(Graph graph, string startingNode)
{
    bool finished = false;
    var queue = graph.Nodes.Values.ToList();
    while (!finished)
    {
        Node nextNode = queue.OrderBy(n => n.DistanceFromStart).FirstOrDefault(
        n => !double.IsPositiveInfinity(n.DistanceFromStart));
        if (nextNode != null)
        {
            var connections = node.Connections.Where(c => queue.Contains(c.Target));
            foreach (var connection in connections)
            {
              double distance = node.DistanceFromStart + connection.Distance;
              if (distance < connection.Target.DistanceFromStart)
                  connection.Target.DistanceFromStart = distance;
            }
            queue.Remove(nextNode);
        }
        else
        {
            finished = true;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: The weights are limited to 0 < w < 1.

EDIT 2: In case someone looks at this and makes the same mistake as me: I just realized I was ordering my neighbors' weights in increasing order instead of decreasing, which is why my paths were incorrect. I changed to:

```
queue.OrderByDescending(n => n.DistanceFromStart).FirstOrDefault(
        n => !double.IsPositiveInfinity(n.DistanceFromStart));
```

and the algorithm is working as expected.

Comment: you seach the MINIMUM weight path, not the maximum, it would be like searching the longest way for a gps

Comment: as Boo said - Dijkstra gives you the minimum length path. If you want to adapt that to the maximum and the maximum you can encounter in a path is 1.0 you would have to subtract the edge's weight from 1.0 and feed that as the value into the algorithm.

Comment: My weights are limited to 0 < w < 1...I updated the question.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to solve Longest Path Problem, which is significantly harder than Shortest Path Problem, and is NP-Complete. (Unless your graph is a DAG or something like that).

Comment: If we had a bound on the number of edges on the path and didn't allow cycles, we could use Dijkstra's, correct?

Comment: can your graph have cycles?

Comment: It can. Would changing the weights from `w` to `1 - w` work in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change all of your weights `w` to `1.0 - w` and Dijkstras will work out-of-the-box.

Converting it to find the maximum path *might* work but even if you could modify the algorithm to work, the effort is for naught when you could just do the above.